# Iframe code not executing when injected

Tags: javascript, iframe

I've been trying to use this code in some XSS research I am conducting. I wish to spawn an iframe on a vulnerable page, with the text of my choosing. If I take the below code and put it in html tags and browse to it, then the iframe is created as expected with the text. However, if I try to inject the code into my test surface (damn vulnerable web application), the iframe window is spawned but no text is produced. Can anyone tell me what's happening here and if there is a way to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function populateIframe() {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write("hello world!");
        ifrm.document.close();
    }
</script>
<body onload="populateIframe();">
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try closing your `<script>` tag.**

---

If that doesn't help, **it's possible that `populateIframe()` is not being called**.

Without knowing your situation exactly, I venture that the vulnerable page already has a `<body>` element that's interfering with your second one's wanting to load..not precisely sure what happens when there are 2 `body` tags. If this is the case, you might remove the extra `body` tag and replace the `iframe` with:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" onload="populateIframe();"></iframe>
```

Then your JS will be called when the `iframe` is done being added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry the closing script tag is there in my original source, I must have forgotten to indent it when typing in my code. Changing the event handler to onload did the trick - I'd tried a million variations but all had the event handler in a separate piece of html. Thanks a lot!